# How do I perform an export that is compatible with ES5 and ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm writing a "class" in node

```
// mymodule/index.js

function MyClass() {}
MyClass.prototype.method1 = function() {..}
```

usually I do

```
module.exports = MyClass
```

but I want my class available for both syntax

```
var MyClass = require('mymodule')
```

and

```
import {MyClass} from 'mymodule'
```

Which is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Take a look at how Babel approaches this: http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/modules/#interop

Comment: Why do you want `import {MyClass} from 'mymodule'` instead of `import MyClass from 'mymodule'`? `var MyClass = require('mymodule')` is equivalent to `import MyClass from 'mymodule'` and `import {MyClass} from 'mymodule'` is equivalent to `var MyClass = require('mymodule').MyClass`. While you can certainly achieve what you want, the question is whether it makes sense.

Comment: You probably mean how to perform an export that is both compatible with CommonJS and ES6's Harmony.

Comment: @E_net4 yes, that's I want

Comment: @FelixKling in the past I tried to use ES6 for some tests (the project is written in CommonJS form) using mocha but I can't because mocha is not ES6/Harmony compatible, that's way i'm asking. Your example has clarified matters further me

Comment: Sure. My point was that `module.exports = MyClass` (probably) works just fine for `import MyClass from 'mymodule'`. But if you want to use `import {MyClass} from 'mymodule'`, you would have to write `module.exports = MyClass; exports.MyClass = MyClass;`. Related: I just compile my code, including tests and let mocha run on the compiled code.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, I have another related question I'll update the question for adding the case. It's about use the index.js file

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, that has nothing to do with the syntax, but with the module loader (which is totally separate).

Comment: Then the last time I had problems was with the module loader?

Comment: My hunch is that you just have to move everything to a common ground: babel all the modules.

Answer (score 19):

As far as writing an export that is compatible for both ES5 and ES6, Babel already takes care of that for you. (As communicated in the comments to your question. I'm only clarifying for those who got lost in the dialog.)

```
module.exports = MyClass
```

will work with both `var MyClass = require('mymodule')` and `import MyClass from 'mymodule`

However, to be clear, the actual syntax you asked about:

```
import {MyClass} from 'mymodule'
```

means something different from

```
import MyClass from 'mymodule'
```

For the latter, you would have to export it as: `module.exports.MyClass = MyClass`, and for ES5 modules it would have to required as `var MyClass = require('mymodule').MyClass`

Comment: I am using this and it's working fine with `require(..)`. But when I am using `import foo from './foo.js'` I am facing an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './foo.js' does not provide an export named 'default'`. **foo.js** export `module.exports = new foo()` where **foo** is a class.

Answer (score 7):

Both ways are correct, but try to import in es6 like this without the brackets:

```
import MyClass from 'mymodule'
```

Otherwise you would have to export your function like this:

```
module.exports.MyClass = MyClass
```

and than import it like this:

```
import { MyClass } from 'mymodule'
```

Comment: This is not compatible with es5 which is what OP is asking.

Comment: @Jim The question was how to make es5 compatible with es6.
My answer just points out a mistake int the code
and how to fix it. This is not es6 code only, listing 2 explains how to adjust the es5 code while listing 1 tells how to adjust the es6 code, to fix the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I understand you are trying to run your ES6 frontend code in some mocha unit tests in node. Yes, you can't do that until node support ES6 modules. If I were you, I would use [systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs#nodejs-use) to load code for those mocha tests.
Mocha supports promises, so it should be fairly painless to load any files before tests.

Writing syntax for both will just create more problems for you.