# How to split Redux actions into multiple files

Tags: redux

I have an actions folder with the usual types.js file for my action type constants, plus an index.js file that does the following

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import {
  AUTH_USER,
  UNAUTH_USER,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  FETCH_MESSAGE
} from './types';
```

and also exports functions for all my actions. I'm wondering, is there a way I can create multiple files for defining my actions so index.js doesn't become too long, then import those into my index.js so in my components I can still just do for example `import { loginUser } from '../../actions';` and not have to worry about which file the action is coming from?

Comment: sure why not? create multiple files, then import the contents of those files in this one, then export. what's stoppin ya?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Assuming you have the following **directory structure**:

```
actions/
  index.js
  types.js
  ProductActions.js
```

Inside your **actions/index.js**, write:

```
export * from './ProductActions';
```

Then define **ProductActions.js** as something like:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { ... } from './types';

export const fetchProducts = () => { ... };
export const deleteProduct = () => { ... };
```

Remember to also update your reducers with the new action types file:

```
import { ... } from '../actions/types'
```

Comment: Curious if there is an advantage to doing `export const fetchProducts = () => { ... };` vs `export function fetchProducts() { ... }` besides feeling like an es6 hipster of course?

Comment: @ChrisTsongas, you can use either one. I personally have decided to stick with ES6 syntax, so I hardly ever write the function keyword anymore. But just to make a note, there are differences in scope between using function vs the arrow function syntax. Essentially, the keyword *this* will have a different meaning. See articles like http://jsrocks.org/2014/10/arrow-functions-and-their-scope/

Answer (score 10):

Say for example we have two actions files; actionsA and ActionsB.
Suppose in actionsA we have the following action functions.

```
//actionsA

//You can import your actionTypes here
export function functionActionsA1(){ /* action body ActionsA1 */}

export function functionActionsA2(){ /* action body ActionsA2 */}
```

and in actionsB we have the following code:

```
//actionsB

//You can import your actionTypes here

export function functionActionsB1(){ /* action body ActionsB1 */}

export function functionActionsB2(){ /* action body ActionsB2 */}
```

Say we have a folder actions containing the two files; actionsA and actionsB, and an index.js file.

```
actions/ 
   index.js
   actionsA.js
   actionsB.js
```

In index.js file we import the different actions from actionsA and actionsB and then exports the imported functions.

```
//index.js
import {functionActionsA1, functionActionsA2 } from './actionsA'
import {functionActionsB1, functionActionsB2} from './actionsB'

export functionActionsA1
export functionActionsA2
export functionActionsB1
export functionActionsB2
```

Now you can just import your index file and get the actions you would want to use as shown below:

```
import {functionActionsA1,functionActionsB2} from '../../actions/index'
```

Comment: In attempting a solution like this, I got a parsing error, saying that I needed to wrap what I was exporting (e.g., `functionActionsA1`) in `{}`. So, each export line at the bottom of your index.js file should look more like `export { functionActionsA1 }`.

Comment: In this example I used the [ES6 synthax of exporting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export). I guess you're using ES5 that's why you're having this issue. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241729/how-do-i-perform-an-export-that-is-compatible-with-es5-and-es6)

Comment: also having this problem (actions files getting too 'large'); questionning myself if this is not a sign of bad pattern. Personal opinion, but import to re-export as described here look quite bad, comparing it with combineReducers which is 'splittable' by definition.I'm still unsure where most of the logic should be done (actions or reducers)

Comment: @Ben I think that it really boils down to your preference. I'm a big fan of using [Thunks](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) in my Redux actions, which leads me to house the large majority of my logic in actions. Every Redux-user that I've interacted with seem to follow the same mentality (keep most logic in actions, and have smaller, more concise reducers). Check out this [discussion](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1171) in the Redux GitHub for more info

Comment: Thx for the link! Quite the same, reached the point where `Object.assign({}, state, action.payload)` is the only thing use in my reducers.. windering about those being relevants. Still you get loads of things in actions, was looking for a clean way to split them